# Sending emails from PHPMailer using proxies IP addresses

Tags: php, email, proxy, phpmailer, fsockopen

I need to send emails from **[PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)** using proxies IP addresses, I know that to do so, I need to use the fsockopen function so I can connect to the SMTP account, I also know that if I have to connect to the proxy I have to use the fsockopen function again. But using it fsockopen inside another fsockopen is not doable.

I have transparent proxy and require no authentication. I need to send this to a distant SMTP server of an external Email Service Provider.

**The code I have tried :**

```
<?php

    //SMTP params
    $server      = 'smtp.espdomain.com';
    $server_port = '25';
    $username = 'smtp_login';
    $password = 'smtp_pass';

    //Proxy
    $proxy      = '1.1.1.1';
    $proxy_port = 1111;

    //Open connection
    $socket = fsockopen($proxy, $proxy_port);

    //Send command to proxy
    fputs($socket, "CONNECT $server:$server_port HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: $proxy\r\n\r\n");
    fgets($socket, 334);

    //SMTP authorization  
    fputs($socket, "AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
    fgets($socket, 334);

    fputs($socket, base64_encode($username)."\r\n");
    fgets($socket, 334);

    fputs($socket, base64_encode($password)."\r\n");
    $output = fgets($socket, 235);

    fputs($socket, "HELO $server \r\n"); 
    $output = fgets($socket, 515);

?>
```

And it's not working I'm not sure why?

Could `socat` commands help in this situation or is there any solution or alternative solution to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution using **[socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html)**, Kindly follow these steps :

1. First of all, you'll need to install `socat` on the server, you can do that simply using the command below :

   ```
   yum install socat
   ```
2. Then run the following `socat` command that will bind **`PROXY_IP:PORT`** with **`HOST_ESP:PORT`** :

   ```
   socat TCP4-LISTEN:proxy_port,bind=proxy_IP,fork,su=nobody TCP4:host:port,bind=proxy_IP
   ```
3. Then instead of making a send to the ESP through **`HOST_ESP:PORT`** you could just make it using **`PROXY_IP:PORT`** and `socat` will do the redirection automatically towards **`HOST_ESP:PORT`** using the output of **`PROXY_IP:PORT`**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: just for my ignorance, which of the words in your sample command need to be replaced with actual IPs?

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. @zakaria

Comment: @zakaria You just saved my day man, I'm extremely thankful for you. By the way, if anyone having confusion with the syntax, it's simple: 

The **proxy** here is your server (the same or any other) that will act as a proxy/medium between your application and the SMTP server.  `proxy_IP` = your server's hostname or IP. `proxy_port` = Any available port in your server, this will become the SMTP port in your application to connect to. `host:port` = This is the actual SMTP host & port in that format via which you want to send emails. Run this command in the server which you want to make a proxy.

Comment: Glad I could help brother.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this a repeat of [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088810/sending-emails-from-phpmailer-using-ip-addresses-of-internal-configured-proxies)? I don't see that much has changed.

You are not using the proxy correctly (you can't do sockets inside sockets), but PHPMailer doesn't have any specific proxy support. If it was going to be anywhere, I'd look at setting properties in `SMTPOptions`, though as far as I can see PHP only offers [proxy support in HTTP streams](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) so you may be SOL. It's probably easier to run a local mail server to relay rather than proxy.

Comment: Thanks @Synchro for your quick replay, not sure how I could use SOL in this situation please add an example if you can. (check my update).

Comment: Um, I don't think you know [what SOL means](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/sol)... Sorry!

Comment: When you have a proxy, you don't talk to the final server directly (as you're trying to do). You connect to the proxy and send commands to it *as if* you were talking to the real server. The proxy relays the commands to the target server, and relays responses back to you. In systems that support proxies you normally establish connection to the proxy and pass along the target that you really want to connect to as an additional wrapper around whatever protocol you're talking. PHP doesn't have SMTP proxy support, only HTTP, so you would need to roll your own proxy code, or find a proxy library.

Comment: @Synchro have you come across a proxy library to use with PHP? Google hasn't been helpful for mail purposes.