# Send emails from PHP using an SMTP Proxy

Tags: php, email, proxy, smtp, phpmailer

I often send emails out via SMTP using PHPMailer and everything works very well. However, I need to send some emails using an SMTP Proxy, which I understand PHPMailer doesn't support.

It's quite hard to find out information on this, as I keep finding issues with sending emails from behind a proxy, rather than using a proxy server. However, I think that PHP doesn't support SMTP proxy servers either?

My questions are...

Using PHP, is it possible to send emails using an SMTP proxy server?

If so, what is the process?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending emails from PHPMailer using proxies IP addresses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36137999/sending-emails-from-phpmailer-using-proxies-ip-addresses)

Comment: Thanks @Synchro. I am looking into Chilkat, but I'm trying to find out more info about that 30 day trial part at the moment.
Also, I'm not 100% sure if I can install socat on the server, so I was hoping for a more standard way. I'm awaiting to hear back from the hosts on that. PS Thanks for all your hard work on PHPMailer - it is fantastic.